# displaying json array in expansion tile - flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to display my json array data in expansion tile. i was able to display the data in expansion tile but when i press the expansion tile, it shows nothing. nothing is displayed when expansion tile is pressed.

JSON:

```
{

    “name”: “kris”,
    “age”: 13,
    “class”: “13A”,

}
```

Expansion_tile.dart:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var userData = [];

class ActiveUser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ActiveUserState createState() => new ActiveUserState();
}

class ActiveLevelState extends State<ActiveUser> {
  final String url = "http://35.186.145.243:8080/user?user_id=user3";

  List data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getJsonData();
  }

  Future<String> getJsonData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
    );

    var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
    data = extractdata['user'];
    userData = data;

    setState(
      () {
        var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
        data = extractdata['user'];
      },
    );
    return "Success";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: StuffInTiles(userData[index]['name']),
            ),
          ),
      itemCount: userData.length,
    );
  }
}

class StuffInTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  final String elementList;
  StuffInTiles(this.elementList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles();
  }

  Widget _buildTiles() {
    if (userData.length == 0)
      return ListTile(
        title: Text("Test"),
      );
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(elementList),
      children: map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

I know that i am supposed to write something under children in expansion tile so it displays the content when pressed but i am unsure on how to display the children as it gives me error when i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer already! simple just call the _getChildren method under children properties in expansion tile:

```
List<dynamic> _getChildren() {
      List<Widget> children = [];
      levelsData.forEach((element) {
        children.add(GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print("Tapped"),
          child: ListTile(
            dense: true,
            title: Text("@" + element['name'].toString()),
            subtitle: Text(element['age'].toString()),
          ),
        ));
      });
      return children;
    }

return ExpansionTile(
      title: Text(elementList),
      children: _getChildren(),
    );
```